# What is this 运行 in ...国内的汽车行业与汽车市场运行环境发生了前所未有的改变?

Tags: meaning

> 中国加入世界贸易组织后，国内的汽车行业与汽车市场运行环境发生了前所未有的改变。

Sometimes in colloquial English we say 'shift' to mean 'sell'. Is '运行环境‘ something like that?

运行环境 maybe 'sales environment' or ‘turnover' (交易额） ??

Comment: operating + conditions

Answer (score 3):

国内的汽车行业与汽车市场运行环境发生了前所未有的改变

This segment I would probably translate as "The domestic automobile industry and the operating environment of the automobile market underwent unprecedented changes."

国内的 domestic
汽车行业 automobile industry
与 and
汽车市场运行环境 operating environment of the automobile market
发生了 happened/underwent
前所未有的 unprecedented
改变 changes

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I think I prefer 'the automobile market and the environment in which it operates underwent ....'. We seem to have narrowed 运行 down to 'operate, function'. You don't think it may just mean ‘sales environment'??

Comment: If it were sales environment, the Chinese would probably be 营销环境 or 销售环境. 运营 and 运行 both refer to the "operations" side of a business, something that would be typically managed by a COO. This perhaps includes sales, but also covers marketing, logistics, and strategic partnerships. It's a very "big" word in terms of context.

Answer (score 2):

I think 运行环境 is a typo here.
should had been "运营环境" which then would not only make more sense but also make it easier to translate. (operating environment or something close to it
)

Comment: That is a good suggestion, I like it!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should think of **运行*环境*** as "***conditions*** in which they can **maneuver/operate**." 运行 means operate and 环境 means environment.

So the sentence means like:

After China entered the global market, the conditions in which the domestic auto industry and auto market operate underwent changes that have never happened before.

Comment: Thanks. For 国内 I would use domestic, 前所未有 unprecedented. I am still not to clear about '运行环境‘ or even if I should take them together. Have any better ideas?

Comment: I changed my answer a bit. Perhaps this helps.

Answer (score 0):

"运行"is a action,it means all the actions of "汽车市场".include :"研发""销售""创业""资金筹集""跨国贸易"......